# NoMethodError in SessionsController#create from a rails program

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone help with this error?

[image]

I'm trying to get a user to be able to login with google auth>

Comment: There is no parameter `:user`.

Comment: you need to review the params that you are sending in your request (params[:user] is equal to nil)

Comment: This is what my session controller look like if anyone mind to help me correct it`class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :redirect_if_not_logged_in, only: [:show]
  require 'securerandom'

  def destroy
    session.clear
    flash[:success] = "You have logged out"
    redirect_to '/'
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    render :login
  end

Comment: What is the value of the `params` variable?

Comment: i got nil for the user